How to parametrize a fixture using pytest
I am running into an issue I am not sure how to solve.
I have following fixtures in the conftest.py file:
@pytest.fixture
def input_payload_1() -> pydantic.BaseModel:
   pass

@pytest.fixture
def input_payload_2() -> pydantic.BaseModel:
   pass


and I want to paramtrize my unit test with these fixtures so it gets tested for both. Something like:
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_payload, expected_output",
    [
        ("input_payload_1", {"value"}),
        ("input_payload_2", {"value2"}),
    ],
)
def test_something(input_payload, expected_output):
    result = tested_functionality(input_payload)
    assert result == expected_output


But I am struggling here as I just can't parametrize this. I've managed to get it working for just one fixture by using indirect attribute, but not for more. How would I paramtrize for 2+ fixutres in this scenario?

Instead of making them fixtures, why not just set them as module level constants?

You could use the request fixture:
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def input_payload_1():
    return "value1"

@pytest.fixture
def input_payload_2():
    return "value2"


# test_example.py

def functionality(value):
    return value

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_payload, expected_output",
    [
        ("input_payload_1", {"value1"}),
        ("input_payload_2", {"value2"}),
    ],
)
def test_something(input_payload, expected_output, request):
    result = functionality(request.getfixturevalue(input_payload))
    assert result == expected_output

